# UserDefaults loses data when app is suspended?

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

Hi I am trying to save a boolean value to true just before opening the phone settings.
When navigating to the settings I am setting my bool to true and when reopening the app it should be read and set back to false. This happens in a weird way since one time it works and the next time it dosen't and it keeps going with this pattern.

Anyone has any ideas as to why this could happend?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using ?

Comment: So you're detecting when the settings app is opened and setting a bool? If you're just setting it when you leave the app, then you could just detect the scene change and set it.